# Modifying the models.Integerfield() appearance

Tags: django, form-fields

Apologies if such question has been already asked before but I am not really sure how the feature I need is actually called.

Is it possible to create models.Integerfield() that would look something like this: https://ibb.co/9VhBL5L

where I would be able to define any word to show up beside the Integerfield() instead of "$". For instance, I have a basic mathematics task where kids need to calculate a number of animals in a forest. So the field would be blank and on the side of the field it would say "animals".

So far, I can create only an empty field in Django:

```
answer_1 = models.IntegerField(
min=0,
label='How many animals do you see?')
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is not something you need to do in your models, that is something for your form.

Comment: Sorry, I am not really familiar with the terminology. Where do I start to apply this feature in forms?

Comment: The example you're showing just looks like a standard input field with an extra element next to it (for the $), you should do this in your html. And if you want to make it for multiple fields, you can create your own widget to use in your forms. see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/)